# how to add an bootstrap icon to simple_form's link_to_remove_association and link_to_add_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Like the question says, I would like to put an icon into the `link_to_add_association` and `link_to_remove_association` s.

I'm using Ruby Rails, and `simple_form`, and I would like to put a bootstrap icon, rather than the words 'Add line', and 'Remove'.

This is what the code looks like. The `f`, in the code below is from a loop these are in.

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add line', f, :weeks %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f, :weeks %>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont remember exactly. But u can try passing blocks with do...end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link_to_add_association` is an user defined helper method. In that method, we have `link_to` tag.
Go to your `link_to_add_association` method(It may be in your helper), there should be a `link_to` tag. For example, In my `link_to_add_association`

```
def link_to_add_association(f, association, **args)

###your code goes here 

link_to('#', class: "xyx " , data: {id: xyz}) do 
    "<span class='fa fa-male fa-lg'>".html_safe
 end

end
```

I have used the font-awesome icon. You can use bootstrap icon instead.

Reference: [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: I'm not seeing this method anywhere in my project. The only thing that references it is a 'console_warn'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you received an answer to your question yet but have you tried checking your attr_accessible in Dashacts. I think you need to add options_attributes.

Tell me how that works out for you.

Comment: I don't have a Dashacts file in my project at all. Does this normally appear in Rails apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer.
I am using ***rails 5.2.*** ***Ruby version 2.4.1***

***The correct Version is***.

```
.links
      = link_to_add_association f, :user_permissions, partial: 'permissions/shared/user_permission_fields', class: 'btn btn-primary' do
        %i.fa.fa-fw.fa-database
```

***The mistake is you put 'Add new'***

```
.links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add New', f, :user_permissions, partial: 'permissions/shared/user_permission_fields', class: 'btn btn-primary' do
        %i.fa.fa-fw.fa-database
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap or font awesome icon can be added by using a block like this:

```
<%= link_to_remove_association f, :weeks do %>
  <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
<% end %>
```

This will replace "Remove" with the minus icon.